# No StreamReader constructor accepting a string

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard-1.6

I'm porting a .NET 4.6.1 console app to .NET Core.

I have NETStandard.Library 1.6 installed, and it's not letting me pass a file path string into a StreamReader constructor. Viewing the definition confirms that it's not available:

[image]

Where's it gone?

Comment: Change your .NET app to first open file stream and then pass it to StreamReader?

Comment: Thanks - I've done that, but I was also trying to get some insight into whether I have my configuration / dependencies set up wrong, or if this is intended.

Comment: No your configuration is fine. It is not there in Core as you can see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.io.streamreader

Answer (score 3):

This is correct. .Net Core 1.0/.Net Standard 1.x refactored the base libraries, so that basic stream types like `StreamReader` are in [the `System.IO` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO/4.1.0) and `FileStream` is in [the `System.IO.FileSystem` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem/4.0.1). Since the constructor you're looking for would require `StreamReader` to depend on `FileStream`, it was removed.

Note that a large part of this refactoring was reversed for the upcoming .Net Core 2.0/.Net Standard 2.0, so [you will be able to use this constructor on .Net Core in the future](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String)).